# Need help on Python 3.4.3 classes: I wrote a program that works, now I need to use classes in it

Tags: python

Here is a clip of my program

```
import os.path

#define global variables
database = []#list to store monthly temperatures
DAYS = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
WEEKS = 6
```

This function read input from a text file and adds the data to the
list called database. The data values are added as strings.
Data for each week is one row in the list.

```
def getInputFromFile(filename = None):
    result = False
    if(filename == None):
        filename = input("Enter name of input file: ")
    if(os.path.isfile(filename)):
        infile = open(filename, 'r')
        count = 0
        for line in infile:
            week = line.strip()
            weekList = week.split()
            database.append(weekList)
            count += 1
        infile.close()
        return True
    else:
        print("Invalid filename ... aborting ...")

    return False

'''
This function creates and returns a list with seven values,
each one being a day average for that month.
'''
def getWeekAverages():
    pass
    weekAverages = []
    MAX = WEEKS
##    total = 0
    for week in range (WEEKS):
        total = 0
        for day in range(len(DAYS)):
          total += int(database[week][day])
        weekAverages.append(total/7)
    return weekAverages

def getDayAverages():
    pass
    dayAverages = []
    MAX = WEEKS
    for day in range(len(DAYS)):
        total = 0
        for week in range (WEEKS):
            total += int(database[week][day])
        dayAverages.append(total/WEEKS)
    return dayAverages
```

### Highest day average

```
def getHighestDayAverage(dayAverages):
    return max(dayAverages)


## Lowest day average
def getLowestDayAverage(dayAverages):
    return min(dayAverages)
```

In my def main everything works. It pulls the file and does all the calculations...Now I have to do this program into classes..need some help on that.

Comment: Don't see the need of any class.

Answer (score 0):

What were you hoping to do with the classes?

I'd look into some object oriented design principles if you aren't sure:

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/python-from-scratch-object-oriented-programming--net-21476